# How to automate render a folder with multiple files in 3ds Max?

Tags: python, automation, render, 3dsmax, maxscript

So, I got a new job and I am a novice in programming. They need me to automate the process of rendering a folder with multiple files. At the same time, I need that each file merge with a xref scene for the render.

The step-by-step is:

- open the .max file
- merge with the xref scene
- make a render with each camera in the scene
- save in another folder
- repeat the process with the next file.

I started making a bot with python using the pyautogui, but that looks totally not efficient once that if somebody touch anything in the mouse or keyboard it can totally interfere with the process. Now I am studying MaxScript to try to make this process within the software itself.

So, if anyone could help me saying if it is possible to do what I want with MaxScript or if I should look for another way I would be really thankful.

Comment: Hey, congrats to your new job! Looks like it involves programming? Maybe pick a basic Python tutorial. You may be overthinking this. Or at least I don't see where the bot is needed, or a GUI. Just pass an input and output folder name to a script and have it do its work. You may also want to check [ask].

Comment: Thanks, Robert. Really appreciate your help. I will try to improve my text question next time.

So, it is possible to make all this steps without even using 3ds Max?